# Wordpress site hosted on Pressable keeps deleting files unknowingly?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, hosting

I'm maintaining a Wordpress site on Pressable and my edits I make to the site keeps disappearing every week.

I update or modify some code that belongs to my site via the built in Wordpress editor and the changes will last last a few days but then the changes just get removed and the site reverts back to getting some errors in the console due to some JS not being executed correctly.. The same problem I fixed just previously.

Specifically, I get an error in the console that says a couple of JS files are missing from my project (getting 'is not a function' in the console), however after I add those JS files and fix the errors, the site remains stable for a week or so before the same file gets deleted and I have to make the fix again...

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: Was the site previously hacked? Could be some backdoor code executing.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... But I will look into that. Are there any obvious indications of WP being hacked?

Comment: Do a quick search of all files for terms like 'preg_replace' and 'eval'.